# Import postgresql database using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, import, dump, pg-restore

I want to import .dump using pg_restore command,
I've created a database using `createdb` command.
I've connected as superuser.
I run the command  `pg_restore -h localhost -p 5410 -U user -d mydb -v 20220711.dump`
I get this on the terminal

```
    pg_restore: connexion ▒ la base de donn▒es pour la restauration
    pg_restore: cr▒ation de SCHEMA mydb
    pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] Erreur pendant le traitement de la TOC (▒ PROCESSING TOC ▒) :
    pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] Erreur ▒ partir de l'entr▒e TOC 13 ; 2615 16391 SCHEMA mydb mydb
    pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] could not execute query: ERREUR:  droit refus▒ pour la base de donn▒es mydb
        La commande ▒tait : CREATE SCHEMA mydb;
[pg_restore: [archive program (db)] could not execute query: ERROR: permission denied for database mydb
     The command was: CREATE SCHEMA mydb;]
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] could not execute query: ERREUR:  le sch▒ma ▒ mydb▒ n'existe pas
        La commande ▒tait : ALTER SCHEMA mydb OWNER TO mydb;
```

Comment: Can you configure your error to be generated in English?

Comment: The issue is the `user` in `-U user` does not have sufficient privileges to do `CREATE SCHEMA mydb;`. You need to restore with  `-U` set to a user that does have the necessary privileges.

Comment: This user does not have permission to create the "CREATE SCHEMA mydb;"  ? are you sure that is a super user ?

Comment: Are you connecting to the OS as a superuser, or to the database as a superuser?  'user' would be an atypical name for the PostgreSQL superuser.